# How to create dynamic table rows with loop on pdf in flutter (use pdf package)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I want to create a pdf document with the package 'pdf'. I show long list in table on the pdf.
I want to create a dynamic table in the pdf document.

I cannot dynamically and programatically create all row in the table.
I cannot show long list in table.........

```
  static Future<File> generateTable(
      List<ReportPerson>? report_list,
      String name,
      String phone,
      String date1,
      String date2,
      String time1,
      String time2,
      BuildContext context) async {
    BlocProvider.of<Show_ProgrssIndicator_Bloc>(context)
        .add(Toggle_progressview());

    var datafont = await rootBundle.load("fonts/IRANSansWeb(FaNum).ttf");
    final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(datafont);

    final headers = ['واحد', 'تعداد', 'نوع بار', 'ردیف'];

    final data = report_list!
        .map((users) =>
            [users.type, users.productCount, users.productName, users.radif])
        .toList();

    //print (data);

    final pdf = pw.Document();

    pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
        build: (context) {
          return <pw.Widget>[
            pw.Column(children: [
              pw.Row(children: [
                pw.Text(name),
                pw.Text("name: "),
              ]),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 10),
              pw.Table.fromTextArray(
                  headers: headers,
                  data: data,
                  cellAlignment: pw.Alignment.center,
                  columnWidths: {
                    0: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(15),
                    1: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(9),
                    2: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(13),
                    3: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(10),
                    4: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(13),
                    5: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(15),
                    6: const pw.FlexColumnWidth(13),
                  }),
            ]),
          ];
        },

        //   pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a6,

        textDirection: pw.TextDirection.rtl,
        theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
          base: ttf,
        )));

    BlocProvider.of<Show_ProgrssIndicator_Bloc>(context)
        .add(Toggle_progressview());
    return saveDocument(name: 'ReportFile.pdf', pdf: pdf);
```

Comment: Hey Ali, what content are you trying to show in your list? is it the `data` field?

Comment: @developer-extraordinare      Hey، report customer orders

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66724731/608266