# Creating a resizeable table that resizes when dragged from corners and sides in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, resize

Here is what i want

[image]

Hello, I made a table with ***Flutter***, I need help resizing my table ***INSIDE*** the app by dragging its corners(like in the image) and not by changing sizes in the code. I found a question like this but with an image, and I couldn't integrate that into my code correctly. Can someone help me? ***I'll link the question here.***
[Creating Resizable View that resizes when pinch or drag from corners and sides in FLUTTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924384/creating-resizable-view-that-resizes-when-pinch-or-drag-from-corners-and-sides-i)

Update: I also found a question like that with a table but it has private packages which I can't use, I will link it here too just in case` [Create dynamic table rows in PDF document using the pdf package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037185/create-dynamic-table-rows-in-pdf-document-using-the-pdf-package)

***And I'll put my code here.***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        //backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100], //background color of scaffold
        appBar: AppBar(
          //title:const Text("Flutter Table"), //title of app
          backgroundColor: Colors.white, //background color of app bar
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child:Table(
              border: TableBorder.all(width:1, color:Colors.black45), //table border
              children: const [

                TableRow(
                    children: [
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("S/N")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Name")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Address")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Nation")
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                ),

                TableRow(
                    children: [
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("1.")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Krishna Karki")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Nepal, Kathmandu")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Nepal")
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                ),

                TableRow(
                    children: [
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("2.")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("John Wick")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("New York, USA")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("USA")
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                ),

                TableRow(
                    children: [
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("3.")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Fedrick May")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Berlin, Germany")
                          )
                      ),
                      TableCell(
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child:Text("Germany")
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                ),
              ],)
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks`
[image]